# Jira - XRay- How to get the total of defects created during a test execution

Tags: jira-rest-api, jira-xray

I'm creating a script that goes into all tests into a test execution. I'd like to get the amount of defects for that particular test execution. Is that a way to get it using rest api?

Comment: Please show what you have tried already and please read, [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Is your question related to ruby, the jira api, specs or a rest api. Please add more details.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the inconvenience. My question is related to rest api (most specific, x-ray) . I've tried using testrun() /defect but all I get is a 404 error

Comment: This? https://confluence.xpand-it.com/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=27534752#content/view/27534752 maybe you should add the Code or command you have executed. And add jira and / or x-ray tags so that users know what you are using and doing.

Comment: Api description https://confluence.xpand-it.com/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=32804707#content/view/32804707

Comment: Hello @Christian, I've tried using this in order to get the defect "/rest/raven/1.0/api/testrun/{id}/defect" but it returns a 404 error
using "rest/raven/1.0/api/testexec/<testExecution>" I can get all the details of the test execution and all the defects opened for each test case . But I cant get the total of defects

Answer (score 0):

Xray enables exporting Cucumber tests to be exported as .feature file that further can be used in your automated tests. To do so use [this export endpoint](https://confluence.xpand-it.com/display/public/XRAY/Exporting+Cucumber+Tests+-+REST)

To import the automated test results back to Jira used [this import endpoint](https://confluence.xpand-it.com/display/public/XRAY/Importing+Cucumber+Tests+-+REST)

Usually APIs will be executed in conjunction with CI/CD tools, like Jenkins.

[In this article](https://confluence.xpand-it.com/display/XRAY32/Defects+count) you can see that the total number of defects can be view via the Jira UI.

And finally, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kigz-xF2-9g) shows how tests are imported and exported via the UI.

Tests can be created via API as well, see [here](https://confluence.xpand-it.com/display/XRAY31/Tests+-+REST#Tests-REST-CreatingandEditingTests-JiraRESTAPI).

I think it all depends on your [testplans](https://confluence.xpand-it.com/display/public/XRAY/Test+Plans+-+REST). When those contain all tests you should be able to execute the test via the endpoint `rest/raven/1.0/api/testexec/<testExecution>`.

Maybe it will be good to ask the very same question in the [atlassian community](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/forums/searchpage/tab/message?advanced=false&allow_punctuation=false&q=x-ray).

Sorry for not being able to fully answer your question, but I think you now should have some things to read :)

Comment: Hello there,Tx for the help

Comment: Let me know if you fixed your issue or not. Thx!

Comment: Hello @Christian, no success yeat Ill try creating a filter using the rest api and retrieve the defects from there... it should work

Answer (score 0):

There is one way that is more straightforward.
You can make use of the ["Test Execution Defects" custom field](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Using+custom+fields#Usingcustomfields-TestExecutionDefects), which is a calculated field.

Then you just need to use Jira's REST API and obtain information for the related Test Execution issue, for that specific custom field that returns an array. The number of elements corresponds to the number of defects.

Example of HTTP GET request:

```
https://sandbox.xpand-it.com/rest/api/2/issue/BOOK-31?fields=customfield_11802
```

Example of response:

```
{
  "expand": "renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations",
  "id": "20130",
  "self": "https://sandbox.xpand-it.com/rest/api/2/issue/20130",
  "key": "BOOK-31",
  "fields": {
    "customfield_11802": [
      "20131"
    ]
  }
}
```

Another way would be to use the JQL function "defectsCreatedDuringTestExecution ()", as mentioned here: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Enhanced+querying+with+JQL
Then you could do a Jira REST API search call.

Example of HTTP GET search request using the JQL function:
https://sandbox.xpand-it.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=issue%20in%20defectsCreatedDuringTestExecution(BOOK-31)